# Error: Could not create NMClient object: Could not connect: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, macos, electron, nmcli

I'm trying to run an electron app inside a docker container on my MacOS. I need "network manager" for the project because the electron app has a dependency on it.
I am using Node 14 as base image.

I installed network manager using "apt install network-manager" and it installed:
`nmcli tool, version 1.14.6`

But when I run `nmcli` command, I get the error:
`Error: Could not create NMClient object: Could not connect: No such file or directory.`

I've tried looking around a lot, even asked AI tools for help, but I can't find a proper explanation or any solution.

I tried running the project on `Ubuntu 16.04` base image and there after installing `network-manager`, the `nmcli` command worked fine (`nmcli tool, version 1.2.6`). So I decided to use that but only to realise that the electron app I am trying to setup, has a peer dependency to `libgpiod` package and that's not available for Ubuntu 16. I tried building it from source, didn't work.

I also tried to compile `network-manager` ver 1.2.6 in my node image, but that didn't work either.

Could someone help me understand how I can get `nmcli` command work in my node image? Or explain me why would it not work in node image but would work in ubuntu image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project as you've described it can't usefully run in a Docker container.  Run it directly on the host system.

NetworkManager is a tool to manage the *host's* network environment.  Its primary interface [appears to be](https://networkmanager.dev/docs/developers/) via a D-Bus socket; this path is hard to access from in a container.  (See for example [DBus communication from docker to host and reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043565/dbus-communication-from-docker-to-host-and-reverse).)  Similarly, Electron is a toolkit to write desktop GUI applications using the Javascript Web ecosystem, but running GUI applications in Docker is tricky ([Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-linux-docker-container)).

In theory, if you (a) run as root on the host, so you can access the Docker socket; (b) bind-mount `/var/run/dbus` to get access to the host's DBus socket; and (c) do the extended work to get access to the host display; then it might be possible to run this

```bash
xauth nlist :0 | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f /tmp/docker.xauth nmerge -
sudo docker run \
  -v /var/run/dbus:/var/run/dbus \
  -v /tmp/.X0-unix:/tmp/.X0-unix \
  -v /tmp/docker.xauth:/root/.Xauthority
  -e DISPLAY=:0.0 \
  your-image
```

This will only work on a native Linux host system, and then only if you're using the Docker Engine directly and not Docker Desktop.

Running outside a container will be far easier, particularly since this last command block is something your end user will need to run every time they run the application.

Comment: Thanks @David for your answer and taking out time to explain.
Yes it was quite tricky to run the GUI application from container but thanks to https://jaked.org/blog/2021-02-18-How-to-run-Electron-on-Linux-on-Docker-on-Mac I was able to get the GUI part working.
I will now try to understand this better and if there is way, I will try to find how I can access the host network from the container.
I am not particularly concerned about the end user as this is only for local development machine (which is a Mac OS).

Comment: On a MacOS system, NetworkManager won't be running anywhere at all.  Neither the host OS, the hidden Docker Linux VM, nor the container will be running it.  Using a Linux VM instead of Docker might be a better match here.  In general, a Docker container is an isolated environment, and if you need to manage the host network, you wouldn't try to do that from inside a container.